# Search Form with Rails:When I type in full email or username, results don't come back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, search

I'm trying to make a search form with Ruby on Rails. Part of it is successful and part of it is not. If i type in a part of the usernames of emails I have registered, results come back. But when I type in the full username of a user, no results come back. Here is my user.rb file:

```
def self.search(search)
  where("username LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
  where("email LIKE ?", "%#{search}%")
end
```

My search_controller.rb:

```
def index 
  @users = User.all
  if params[:search]
    @users = User.search(params[:search]).order("created_at DESC")
  else
    @users = User.all.order('created_at DESC')
  end
end
```

And finally my view:

```
<%= form_tag(search_path, :method => 'get', id: 'search-form') do %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], placeholder: "Search Users" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>

<% if params[:search].present? %>
  <% if @users.present? %>
    <h1><li>Search Results for: "<%= params[:search] %>":</li></h1>

    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <li><a href="/users/<%= user.username %>"><%= user.username %></a></li>
      <li><a href="/users/<%=user.username%>"><%= user.email %></a></li>
      <br />
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <p>There are no users with the term(s) <%= params[:search] %>.</p>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <title>Search Users</title>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method only returns the result of the second `where`. To fix this combine both queries into one:

```
def self.search(search)
  where('username LIKE :query OR email LIKE :query', { query: "%#{search}%" })
end
```

Comment: Thx for your answer, let me test that piece of code now.